# Show image on screen with ursina

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

I'm making a 3D FPS in Ursina, and I'd like to have my arm skin with the weapon as an image, not an actual 3D model. Does anyone know how to do this ? I tried with Animate from the documentation, but this loads an image as an object in my scene.

What I could do is define a quad with player as parent, and positional arguments, so that it follows me and I see it at the right place, but even this wouldn't work as the texture argument doesn't accept gifs.

So, does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Create the entity with `parent=camera.ui` to give it a position on the interface instead of the scene (world). I elaborated in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can load an animated gif with `Animation()` which creates an entity. As part of the interface you'll want to attach it to the UI:

```py
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()
gif = 'animation.gif'
a = Animation(gif, parent=camera.ui)
a.scale /= 5 # adjust right size to your needs
a.position = (0.5, -0.5) # lower right of the screen
app.run()
```

You will need the `imageio` Python package installed to load gifs.

---

OLD ANSWER

The Entity you use for the gun has to be anchored to the interface using its `parent` parameter. Here's an example for a Minecraft-style hand (just a block really):

```py
class Hand(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent=camera.ui,
            model='cube',
            position=Vec2(0.5, -0.3),
            scale=(0.2, 0.2, 0.5),
            rotation=(150, -30, 0)
        )
```

The important part is `parent=camera.ui`

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do this ; it's not what I meant. What I mean is : is there a way i can show an image on screen, that's not a 3D model ? So my armes aren't a cube, minecraft-like, but rather a 2D image that I can see. Like, you got your health bar : that's not a 3D model that follows you, it's 2D on the screen, and I'd like to have an image this way

Comment: make it a `quad` and set your texture

Comment: Yeah, but did you read what I wrote ? The texture doesn't accept gifs or animated things, meaning I have my hands, but can't animate them

Comment: You didn't mention animated gifs before, you merely talked about an image. I'm not sure if Ursina accepts gif animations although it does support video textures. Have you had a look at the Texture section in the [Entity Basics](https://www.ursinaengine.org/entity_basics.html)?

Comment: @QuantumSushi I updated my answer for animated gifs. Please let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I cannot seem to find a way to play gifs. I know, [@Jan Wilamowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15744300/jan-wilamowski) updated his answer but, in my project, that does NOT work. You CAN show static images on this screen, though, by making a `quad` entity with an image texture, as shown:

```
class yourimage(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent=camera.ui,
            model='quad',
            #size, position, and rotate your image here
            texture = 'yourimage')
yourimage()
```